# Kubernetes NetworkPolicy - Is there a way to identify which NetworkPolicies are applied to Pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

We have 3-4 different NetworkPolicy in our Namespace and they are applied based on Pod Selector. Want to know is there any way from Pod side to know which NetworkPolicy is applied on it?

Answer (score 1):

The output of `kubectl get network policy` should display the pod-selector.
After that you can use `kubectl get pod -l key=value` to list the pods affected.

you can automate this using a bash script/function.

I would also recommend checking "kubectl np-viewer" which is a kubectl plugin, can be [found here](https://github.com/runoncloud/kubectl-np-viewer). This plugin has what you are asking for out of box.

`kubectl np-viewer -p pod-name` prints network policies rules affecting a specific pod in the current namespace

Answer (score 1):

If POD selector used you can use the simple way

```
kubectl get pod -l \
  $( \
        kubectl get netpolicies <netpolicy-name> \
        -o jsonpath="{.spec.podSelector.matchLabels}"| \
        jq -r 'to_entries|map("\(.key)=\(.value)")[]' \
  )
```

This will get the policy selector and use it as input and list the pods

**Any way from Pod side**

There is **no POD** side you can check, however I read somewhere `kubectl describe pod-name` could show Network Policies I tested not showing at least in minikube

[image]

So you can use the above command or describe the **networkpolicy** itself to get **POD selector** and get an idea.

```
kubectl describe networkpolicies <name of policy>
```